# When passing an Object into a class how can I access it's vars/functions?

Tags: java, processing

I hope this doesn't sound too dumb and makes sense.

```
class Test {
  int num;
  public Object obj;

  public Test(int num, Object obj){
    this.num = num;
    this.obj = obj;
  }

  int getNum(){
    return num;
  }

}

class Bird {
  public int size;

  public Bird(int size){
    this.size = size;
  }

  public void setSize(int size){
    this.size = size;
  }

  public int getSize(){
    return size;
  }

}
```

```
 void setup(){
   size(100, 100);

   Bird y = new Bird(7);
   Test x = new Test(4, y);

   //x.obj.size does not work
   //x.obj.getSize() does not work
 }
```

So I have these two files. The first has the classes and the second actually runs it. After passing in the Object trying to access the vars or functions of that class does not work. Is there a way to make this work?

I was originally trying to find a way to make an ArrayList of functions (Without Lambda) since this was becoming fruitless I've thought about changing my way.

I have also tried making `public Object obj;` into `public Bird obj;` and this didn't change anything.

Am I on the right track? Is there a good way to do something like this?

I will also note that this is written in Processing 3.5. It is like Java with minor syntax changes so that's why somethings might not look right. This is also why Lambdas don't work.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: In straight Java, ```Bird x = new Test(...)``` should fail to compile, since a Test is not a Bird.  Does "Processing" let you do that?  Gack!

Comment: @another-dave OOPS! accidently switched those around! It does not. I'll fix that right now, but that was not a problem in my original code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Kevin explained the problem. However, you could use [generics](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/types.html) to tell the compiler what type you are going to put in and not have to restrict the type or do a dangerous cast since it's not always easy to guarantee the object's type.

```
class Test<T> {
  int num;
  public T obj;

  public Test(int num, T obj){
    this.num = num;
    this.obj = obj;
  }

  int getNum(){
    return num;
  }

}

class Bird {
  public int size;

  public Bird(int size){
    this.size = size;
  }

  public void setSize(int size){
    this.size = size;
  }

  public int getSize(){
    return size;
  }

}
void setup(){
   size(100, 100);

   Bird y = new Bird(7);
   Test<Bird> x = new Test<>(4, y);
}
```

Comment: Ah so this is the same as Kevins but I could put in any class. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

If you have a variable of type `Object`, then the compiler only "knows" about the functions inside the `Object` class.

If you want to use functions from a more specific type, you have to **cast** the variable, like this:

```java
Bird z = (Bird) x.obj;
println(z.size);
```

Note that this doesn't actually change the type of the object, it just tells the compiler what type to expect. If the variable isn't actually a `Bird`, then this will fail.

Or you could change your `obj` variable to a more specific type:

```java
class Test {
  int num;
  public Bird obj;

  public Test(int num, Bird obj){
    this.num = num;
    this.obj = obj;
  }

  // ...
```

Now you can access the functions from the `Bird` class:

```java
println(x.obj.size);
```

Shameless self-promotion: [here](https://happycoding.io/tutorials/processing/creating-classes) is a tutorial on creating classes in Processing.

Comment: Shouldn't you suggest generics so you don't have to restrict the type? `public Test(int num, T obj){` then you get help from the compiler and can still accept any object

Comment: @JuanMendes I think generics are overkill for what OP is trying to do, but feel free to post your suggestion as an answer.

Comment: If generics would allow me to pass in any kind of class I would like to know.

Comment: Also the methods you shown do work. I swore I made Test take in a bird. This will work for getting me starting though it feels like this may become rather hardcoded. I would like to be able to pass any object into Test and use whatever class functions it may have. Is this something I can do?

Comment: @DerekC.If you need to access the functions of the `Bird` class, why do you want to pass in any class?

Comment: @KevinWorkman because in the future I would like my project to be versitiale. Bird is simply the example I made.

Comment: @DerekC.I would focus on getting the basics working before you worry too much about expanding the scope. You might also want to look into [inheritance](https://happycoding.io/tutorials/java/inheritance), but again, I would focus on the basics first if I were you.

Comment: @KevinWorkman Yeah for sure. I was getting very frustrated getting my foot hold. Now I can start getting my ideas out at least for one specific case. I will surely expand at a later date. Thanks so much for the help!